# How to determine rotational energy of gas molecules

Tags: statistical-mechanics, molecules, gas

For an arbitrary polyatomic molecular gas, what is the expected behavior of $U_{rot}(T)$, the rotational kinetic energy of the atoms, in the two limits T high and T low?

So far, I have written an expression for the average energy of the gas including terms for translational kinetic energy and vibrational energy, the latter of which depends on the grand canonical partition function. However I have not figured out how to quantify the rotational kinetic energy (other than as the sum of $I \omega^2$ for all particles. However, since this does not depend on T, it is not useful for determining expected values at high and low T.

Answer (score 1):

The population over the rotational levels *is* a function of temperature in accordance to Boltzmann's law. For low temperatures, only the lowest rotational levels are populated while for higher temperatures more and more rotational levels get populated and the rotational energy increases accordingly. Note that in the high temperature limit you can replace the summation in the partition function by an integral. For an asymmetric top molecule:

$q_\text{rot}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sigma}\left (\frac{8\pi^2I_aktT}{h^2} \right )^{1/2}\left (\frac{8\pi^2I_bktT}{h^2} \right )^{1/2}\left (\frac{8\pi^2I_cktT}{h^2} \right )^{1/2}$,

where $I_a, I_b,$ and $I_c$ are the moments of inertia around the principle axis of the molecule and $\sigma$ is a constant related to the (point group) symmetry of the molecule.